# angular 4 material, input field and service communication error

Tags: html, angular

The problem is the next. This form has 2 user input field, and if I submit the form, the component send same data from input fields to the service. The form always send the first content. For example I send the next: username = User, note = Note, I got back username = User, note = User.

I think the problem is in my component, where I define the noteText.value but I couldn't find the correct way.

**Service.ts**

```
postNote(note){
            var headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/postnotes', JSON.stringify(note), {headers: headers})
                .map(res => res.json());
        }
```

**Component.ts**

```
postNote(event, noteText,){
    var result;
    var newNote = {
      note: noteText.value,
      country: noteText.value,
      username: noteText.value 
    };

    result = this.notesService.postNote(newNote);
    result.subscribe(x => {
      this.notes.push(newNote);
      noteText.note = '';
      noteText.username = '';
    });
  }
```

**Component.html**

```
<div class="example-container">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="username" [value]="username" autofocus #noteText>   
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="note" [value]="note" autofocus #noteText> 
        </mat-form-field>
        <button (click)="postNote($event, noteText)">Click me !</button>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ngModel` along with `noteText.username` variable

```
 <input matInput placeholder="username" [(ngModel)]="noteText.username" [value]="username" autofocus #noteText>
```

Comment: Thank you so much !